# What is wrong with my swagger generated API model?

Tags: java, json, swagger

I have a swagger contract from which I generated my API.
I am having trouble deserializing this json:

```
{
"id": 470,
"createdBy": "REPRISE",
"lastModifiedBy": "REPRISE",
"createdDate": "2021-12-07T23:07Z",
"lastModifiedDate": "2021-12-07T23:07Z",
"actif": true,
"noActeurDb2": "3870990101699999999",
"noGefi": null,
"tvaOn": false,
"tvaInterne": true,
"frequenceFacture": "MENSUEL",
"exonereVert": false,
"adresseClient": {
    "id": 470,
    "createdBy": "REPRISE",
    "lastModifiedBy": "REPRISE",
    "createdDate": "2021-12-07T23:38Z",
    "lastModifiedDate": "2021-12-07T23:38Z",
    "actif": true,
    "complementNom": "",
    "rue": "Ch. de l''Usine-à-Gaz",
    "noRue": "483",
    "noEntree": "20",
    "complementRue": "Case postale 299",
    "noPostal": "1000",
    "localite": "Lausanne 16",
    "pays": "Suisse"
},
"utilisations": [
    {
        "id": 2368,
        "createdBy": "REPRISE",
        "lastModifiedBy": "REPRISE",
        "createdDate": "2021-12-07T23:07Z",
        "lastModifiedDate": "2021-12-07T23:07Z",
        "actif": true,
        "dateDebut": "2012-12-31T23:00Z",
        "dateFin": "2014-12-31T23:00Z",
        "priseEnCharge": {
            "id": 3314,
            "createdBy": "REPRISE",
            "lastModifiedBy": "REPRISE",
            "createdDate": "2021-12-07T23:40Z",
            "lastModifiedDate": "2021-12-07T23:40Z",
            "actif": true,
            "lieuPriseEnCharge": null
        },
        "conteneur": {
            "id": 2362,   // this is the field on which the error occurs
            "createdBy": "REPRISE",
            "lastModifiedBy": "REPRISE",
            "createdDate": "2021-12-07T23:07Z",
            "lastModifiedDate": "2021-12-07T23:07Z",
            "actif": true,
            "noConteneur": "null",
            "typeConteneur": null,
            "pesages": null
        },
        "matiere": null,
        "exonerationCode": null
    },
[rest of json file]
```

I have this error:

```
Cannot construct instance of `ch.vdl.cilcamion.client.model.ConteneurEntity` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (2393)
```

On this class:

```
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.languages.JavaClientCodegen", date = "2021-12-13T13:36:15.093+01:00")
public class ConteneurEntity {
  @JsonProperty("actif")
  private Boolean actif = null;

  @JsonProperty("createdBy")
  private String createdBy = null;

  @JsonProperty("createdDate")
  private String createdDate = null;

  @JsonProperty("datePremiereUtilisation")
  private String datePremiereUtilisation = null;

  @JsonProperty("id")
  private Integer id = null;

  @JsonProperty("lastModifiedBy")
  private String lastModifiedBy = null;

  @JsonProperty("lastModifiedDate")
  private String lastModifiedDate = null;

  @JsonProperty("noConteneur")
  private String noConteneur = null;

  @JsonProperty("pesages")
  private List<PesageEntity> pesages = null;

  @JsonProperty("typeConteneur")
  private TypeConteneurEntity typeConteneur = null;

  @JsonProperty("utilisation")
  private UtilisationEntity utilisation = null;

  public ConteneurEntity actif(Boolean actif) {
    this.actif = actif;
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Get actif
   * @return actif
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")
  public Boolean isActif() {
    return actif;
  }

  public void setActif(Boolean actif) {
    this.actif = actif;
  }

  public ConteneurEntity createdBy(String createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Get createdBy
   * @return createdBy
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")
  public String getCreatedBy() {
    return createdBy;
  }

  public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
  }

  public ConteneurEntity createdDate(String createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Get createdDate
   * @return createdDate
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(example = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmX", value = "")
  public String getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
  }

  public void setCreatedDate(String createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
  }

  public ConteneurEntity datePremiereUtilisation(String datePremiereUtilisation) {
    this.datePremiereUtilisation = datePremiereUtilisation;
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Get datePremiereUtilisation
   * @return datePremiereUtilisation
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(example = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmX", value = "")
  public String getDatePremiereUtilisation() {
    return datePremiereUtilisation;
  }

  public void setDatePremiereUtilisation(String datePremiereUtilisation) {
    this.datePremiereUtilisation = datePremiereUtilisation;
  }

  public ConteneurEntity id(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Get id
   * @return id
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")
  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public ConteneurEntity lastModifiedBy(String lastModifiedBy) {
    this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Get lastModifiedBy
   * @return lastModifiedBy
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")
  public String getLastModifiedBy() {
    return lastModifiedBy;
  }

  public void setLastModifiedBy(String lastModifiedBy) {
    this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
  }

  public ConteneurEntity lastModifiedDate(String lastModifiedDate) {
    this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Get lastModifiedDate
   * @return lastModifiedDate
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(example = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmX", value = "")
  public String getLastModifiedDate() {
    return lastModifiedDate;
  }

  public void setLastModifiedDate(String lastModifiedDate) {
    this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
  }

  public ConteneurEntity noConteneur(String noConteneur) {
    this.noConteneur = noConteneur;
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Get noConteneur
   * @return noConteneur
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")
  public String getNoConteneur() {
    return noConteneur;
  }

  public void setNoConteneur(String noConteneur) {
    this.noConteneur = noConteneur;
  }

  public ConteneurEntity pesages(List<PesageEntity> pesages) {
    this.pesages = pesages;
    return this;
  }

  public ConteneurEntity addPesagesItem(PesageEntity pesagesItem) {
    if (this.pesages == null) {
      this.pesages = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    this.pesages.add(pesagesItem);
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Get pesages
   * @return pesages
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")
  public List<PesageEntity> getPesages() {
    return pesages;
  }

  public void setPesages(List<PesageEntity> pesages) {
    this.pesages = pesages;
  }

  public ConteneurEntity typeConteneur(TypeConteneurEntity typeConteneur) {
    this.typeConteneur = typeConteneur;
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Get typeConteneur
   * @return typeConteneur
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")
  public TypeConteneurEntity getTypeConteneur() {
    return typeConteneur;
  }

  public void setTypeConteneur(TypeConteneurEntity typeConteneur) {
    this.typeConteneur = typeConteneur;
  }

  public ConteneurEntity utilisation(UtilisationEntity utilisation) {
    this.utilisation = utilisation;
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Get utilisation
   * @return utilisation
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")
  public UtilisationEntity getUtilisation() {
    return utilisation;
  }

  public void setUtilisation(UtilisationEntity utilisation) {
    this.utilisation = utilisation;
  }


  @Override
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    ConteneurEntity conteneurEntity = (ConteneurEntity) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.actif, conteneurEntity.actif) &&
        Objects.equals(this.createdBy, conteneurEntity.createdBy) &&
        Objects.equals(this.createdDate, conteneurEntity.createdDate) &&
        Objects.equals(this.datePremiereUtilisation, conteneurEntity.datePremiereUtilisation) &&
        Objects.equals(this.id, conteneurEntity.id) &&
        Objects.equals(this.lastModifiedBy, conteneurEntity.lastModifiedBy) &&
        Objects.equals(this.lastModifiedDate, conteneurEntity.lastModifiedDate) &&
        Objects.equals(this.noConteneur, conteneurEntity.noConteneur) &&
        Objects.equals(this.pesages, conteneurEntity.pesages) &&
        Objects.equals(this.typeConteneur, conteneurEntity.typeConteneur) &&
        Objects.equals(this.utilisation, conteneurEntity.utilisation);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(actif, createdBy, createdDate, datePremiereUtilisation, id, lastModifiedBy, lastModifiedDate, noConteneur, pesages, typeConteneur, utilisation);
  }


  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class ConteneurEntity {\n");
    
    sb.append("    actif: ").append(toIndentedString(actif)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    createdBy: ").append(toIndentedString(createdBy)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    createdDate: ").append(toIndentedString(createdDate)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    datePremiereUtilisation: ").append(toIndentedString(datePremiereUtilisation)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    id: ").append(toIndentedString(id)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    lastModifiedBy: ").append(toIndentedString(lastModifiedBy)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    lastModifiedDate: ").append(toIndentedString(lastModifiedDate)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    noConteneur: ").append(toIndentedString(noConteneur)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    pesages: ").append(toIndentedString(pesages)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    typeConteneur: ").append(toIndentedString(typeConteneur)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    utilisation: ").append(toIndentedString(utilisation)).append("\n");
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
  }

  /**
   * Convert the given object to string with each line indented by 4 spaces
   * (except the first line).
   */
  private String toIndentedString(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
      return "null";
    }
    return o.toString().replace("\n", "\n    ");
  }

}
```

I don't understand what is happening, the error comes from the generated API but I can't pinpoint the exact problem. Should I generate the constructors in my model classes maybe ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Sorry I might be wrong in my answer, since the class is generated from swagger it should be ok . Do you have a field with "2393" as value in your json ? There might be a mistake in the input .

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The error occurs here:
"conteneur":{
            "id":2393,
            "createdBy":"REPRISE",
            "lastModifiedBy":"REPRISE",
            "createdDate":"2021-12-07T23:07Z",
            "lastModifiedDate":"2021-12-07T23:07Z",
            "actif":true,
            "noConteneur":"6212109875",
            "typeConteneur":null,
            "pesages":null
         }
With id equal to 2393.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deserialize from Number value to int (error - no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53820087/113116)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deserialize from Number value to int (error - no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53818314/how-to-deserialize-from-number-value-to-int-error-no-int-int-argument-constru)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I had already seen this reply before posting and it doesn't fix my problem ! Could the problem come from the fact that the json is really big (approx. 177k lines) ? I have tried with a smaller json and didn't have the problem. I think it might come from the data but I can't see the problem.