# Cannot construct instance of `Instrutor`: no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I'm trying to build an API with Spring Boot, but I keep getting an error when dealing with @OneToMany entities. The Bean seem to not be able to get an entity I'm referencing by ID through the JSON from the database and constructing it to insert into the other entity. Sounds complicated, so here's the code for everything and the error. I googled and googled and couldn't find a fitting answer to my specific situation.

Entity Turma:

```
package com.residencia.academia.entity;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "turma")
public class Turma {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_turma")
    private Integer idTurma;

    @Column(name = "horario")
    private Date horarioTurma;

    @Column(name = "duracao")
    private Integer duracaoTurma;

    @Column(name = "data_inicio")
    private Date dataInicioTurma;

    @Column(name = "data_fim")
    private Date dataFimTurma;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_instrutor", referencedColumnName = "id_instrutor")
    private Instrutor instrutor;

    public Integer getIdTurma() {
        return idTurma;
    }

    public void setIdTurma(Integer idTurma) {
        this.idTurma = idTurma;
    }

    public Date getHorarioTurma() {
        return horarioTurma;
    }

    public void setHorarioTurma(Date horarioTurma) {
        this.horarioTurma = horarioTurma;
    }

    public Integer getDuracaoTurma() {
        return duracaoTurma;
    }

    public void setDuracaoTurma(Integer duracaoTurma) {
        this.duracaoTurma = duracaoTurma;
    }

    public Date getDataInicioTurma() {
        return dataInicioTurma;
    }

    public void setDataInicioTurma(Date dataInicioTurma) {
        this.dataInicioTurma = dataInicioTurma;
    }

    public Date getDataFimTurma() {
        return dataFimTurma;
    }

    public void setDataFimTurma(Date dataFimTurma) {
        this.dataFimTurma = dataFimTurma;
    }

    public Instrutor getInstrutor() {
        return instrutor;
    }

    public void setInstrutor(Instrutor instrutor) {
        this.instrutor = instrutor;
    }
}
```

Turma's Controller:

```
package com.residencia.academia.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.residencia.academia.entity.Turma;
import com.residencia.academia.service.TurmaService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/turma")
public class TurmaController {

    @Autowired
    private TurmaService turmaService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Turma>> findAll() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(turmaService.findAllTurma());
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Turma> findById(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(turmaService.findByIdTurma(id));
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Turma save(@RequestBody Turma turma) {
        return turmaService.saveTurma(turma);
    }

    @PutMapping
    public Turma update(@RequestBody Turma turma) {
        return turmaService.updateTurma(turma);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        turmaService.deleteTurma(id);
    }
}
```

Turma's Service:

```
package com.residencia.academia.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.residencia.academia.entity.Turma;
import com.residencia.academia.repository.TurmaRepository;

@Service
public class TurmaService {
    
    @Autowired
    private TurmaRepository turmaRepository;
    
    public List<Turma> findAllTurma() {
        return turmaRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    public Turma findByIdTurma(Integer id) {
        return turmaRepository.findById(id).get();
    }
    
    public Turma saveTurma(Turma turma) {
        return turmaRepository.save(turma);
    }
    
    public Turma updateTurma(Turma turma) {
        return turmaRepository.save(turma);
    }
    
    public void deleteTurma(Integer id) {
        turmaRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
    
    public void deleteTurma(Turma turma) {
        turmaRepository.delete(turma);
    }
}
```

Turma's Repository:

```
package com.residencia.academia.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.residencia.academia.entity.Turma;

public interface TurmaRepository extends JpaRepository<Turma, Integer> {

}
```

---

Entity Instrutor:

```
package com.residencia.academia.entity;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "instrutor")
public class Instrutor {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_instrutor")
    private Integer idInstrutor;
    
    @Column(name = "rg")
    private Integer rgInstrutor;
    
    @Column(name = "nome")
    private String nomeInstrutor;
    
    @Column(name = "nascimento")
    private Date dataNascimentoInstrutor;
    
    @Column(name = "titulacao")
    private Integer titulacaoInstrutor;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "instrutor")
    private List<Turma> turmaList;

    public Integer getIdInstrutor() {
        return idInstrutor;
    }

    public void setIdInstrutor(Integer idInstrutor) {
        this.idInstrutor = idInstrutor;
    }

    public Integer getRgInstrutor() {
        return rgInstrutor;
    }

    public void setRgInstrutor(Integer rgInstrutor) {
        this.rgInstrutor = rgInstrutor;
    }

    public String getNomeInstrutor() {
        return nomeInstrutor;
    }

    public void setNomeInstrutor(String nomeInstrutor) {
        this.nomeInstrutor = nomeInstrutor;
    }

    public Date getDataNascimentoInstrutor() {
        return dataNascimentoInstrutor;
    }

    public void setDataNascimentoInstrutor(Date dataNascimentoInstrutor) {
        this.dataNascimentoInstrutor = dataNascimentoInstrutor;
    }

    public Integer getTitulacaoInstrutor() {
        return titulacaoInstrutor;
    }

    public void setTitulacaoInstrutor(Integer titulacaoInstrutor) {
        this.titulacaoInstrutor = titulacaoInstrutor;
    }

    public List<Turma> getTurmaList() {
        return turmaList;
    }

    public void setTurmaList(List<Turma> turmaList) {
        this.turmaList = turmaList;
    }
}
```

Instrutor's Controller:

```
package com.residencia.academia.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.residencia.academia.entity.Instrutor;
import com.residencia.academia.service.InstrutorService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/instrutor")
public class InstrutorController {
    
    @Autowired
    private InstrutorService instrutorService;
    
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Instrutor>> findAll() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(instrutorService.findAllInstrutor());
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Instrutor> findById(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(instrutorService.findByIdInstrutor(id));
    }
    
    @PostMapping
    public Instrutor save(@RequestBody Instrutor instrutor) {
        return instrutorService.saveInstrutor(instrutor);
    }
    
    @PutMapping
    public Instrutor update(@RequestBody Instrutor instrutor) {
        return instrutorService.updateInstrutor(instrutor);
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        instrutorService.deleteInstrutor(id);
    }
}
```

Instrutor's Service:

```
package com.residencia.academia.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.residencia.academia.entity.Instrutor;
import com.residencia.academia.repository.InstrutorRepository;

@Service
public class InstrutorService {
    
    @Autowired
    private InstrutorRepository instrutorRepository;
    
    public List<Instrutor> findAllInstrutor() {
        return instrutorRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    public Instrutor findByIdInstrutor(Integer id) {
        return instrutorRepository.findById(id).get();
    }
    
    public Instrutor saveInstrutor(Instrutor instrutor) {
        return instrutorRepository.save(instrutor);
    }
    
    public Instrutor updateInstrutor(Instrutor instrutor) {
        return instrutorRepository.save(instrutor);
    }
    
    public void deleteInstrutor(Integer id) {
        instrutorRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
    
    public void deleteInstrutor(Instrutor instrutor) {
        instrutorRepository.delete(instrutor);
    }
}
```

Instrutor's Repository:

```
package com.residencia.academia.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.residencia.academia.entity.Instrutor;

public interface InstrutorRepository extends JpaRepository<Instrutor, Integer> {

}
```

JSON Structure:

```
{
    "horarioTurma": "2022-06-29T18:00:00",
    "duracaoTurma": 60,
    "dataInicioTurma": "2022-06-29",
    "dataFimTurma": "2022-07-29",
    "instrutor": 1
}
```

HTTP Response:

```
400 Bad Request

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.residencia.academia.entity.Instrutor` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53818314/how-to-deserialize-from-number-value-to-int-error-no-int-int-argument-constru

Comment: I seen that one, it doesn't help me to fix my issue Scary Wombat.